# Restart the program?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

At the end of my program I prompt the user to press any key to repeat the program.

To enable this option I need first to reset a number of variables to prevent errors from occuring. After that I can safely jump to the start of the program.

Is there a way to restart the program from a scratch so I avoid the bugs that may arise from starting over?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: If you're on a unix OS, you can just use `exec` and friends to quickly and cleanly restart it.

Comment: What OS?  That's the kind of thing I'd so in a startup script/batch file rather than in the program.